# Outlook doesn't like my HTML signature

Tags: html, outlook

I have a PSD that I have made into an HTML signature, however Outlook (2013) doesn't seem to like my HTML and after trying to implement the signature, the formatting is all messed up and the signature looks really bad.

This is what it *should* look like: http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/bowerbird-sig.html

As you can see, it looks just fine in a web browser, but Outlook seems to take it and break it.

Here's the code (forgive me, I'm no HTML ninja):

```html
<div id = "body" style = "margin: 25px 50px;">
<div id = "logo" style = "float: left; display: block; margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 60px;"></div>
<h1 style = "color:#a2967d; font-family: georgia, serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px; margin-left: 30px;">Catherine Heraghty</h1>
<div class = "text" ><span style = "color:#7a7a7a; font-family: century gothic, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; font-weight: normal;">creative director<br/>
m: 0410 525 401<br/>
p: 02 9531 2233<br/>
w: <a style = "color: #7a7a7a; text-decoration: none;" href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au">bowerbirdinteriors.com.au</a></span></div>
<div id = "social" style = "padding-top: 10px;">
 <a href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/Web.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au/collections/"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/Cart.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://instagram.com/bowerbirdinteriors"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/instagram.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://www.facebook.com/bowerbirdinteriorstyling?fref=ts"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/facebook.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://www.pinterest.com/bowerbird/"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/pinterest.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help on how to make this Outlook-compatible would be *greatly* appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is not exactly a bastion of HTML compliance and renders HTML code differently from, say, a Webkit-based browser.

Your best bet is to rewrite your signature using (gasp) tables, if you want Outlook to play nice with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check following which you expected result:

```css
.demo{
  color:#7a7a7a;
  font-family: century gothic, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 13px; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  line-height: 20px; 
  font-weight: normal;
  }

.rightdiv{
  margin-left:30px;
  }
```

```html
<div id = "body" style = "margin: 25px 50px;">
  
<div id = "logo" style = "float: left; display: block; margin-right: 30px; margin-bottom: 60px;"></div>
  <div class="rightdiv">
<h1 style = "color:#a2967d; font-family: georgia, serif; font-size: 16px; font-weight: normal; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 2px;">Catherine Heraghty</h1>
<div class = "text" ><span class="demo">creative director<br/></span><span class="demo">
m: 0410 525 401<br/></span><span class="demo">
p: 02 9531 2233<br/></span><span class="demo">
w: <a style = "color: #7a7a7a; text-decoration: none;" href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au">bowerbirdinteriors.com.au</a></span></div>
<div id = "social" style = "padding-top: 10px;">
 <a href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/Web.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://bowerbirdinteriors.com.au/collections/"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/Cart.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://instagram.com/bowerbirdinteriors"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/instagram.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://www.facebook.com/bowerbirdinteriorstyling?fref=ts"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/facebook.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
 <a href = "http://www.pinterest.com/bowerbird/"><img class = "social" src = "http://theitguy.net.au/bowerbird/pinterest.png" style = "padding-right: 20px;"></a>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps.